# Loop to read/process network is too tight?

Tags: c#, loops

My application starts and paints the MDI Parent form. At that point, it waits for events to happen. In order to start the main loop, the user has to click on a toolbar button. That calls the main processing routine and here is the code.

```
    private void MainAPRSTW_Main()
        {
        //frmSplash objfrmSplash = new frmSplash();
        //objfrmSplash.ShowDialog();

        //this is the main list
        TopNodeList MainList = new TopNodeList(this);

        //setup the filter
        FilterList CallFilter = new FilterList();
        CallFilter.ReadPassList();
        CallFilter.ReadBlockList();

        //load what's in the cache
        MainList.ReadCache(this);

        //initiate the Socket
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream,
                                   ProtocolType.Tcp);

        //initiate the endpoints
        IPEndPoint AGWPEServer=new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(AGWIPAddress), AGWPort);

        try
            {
            server.Connect(AGWPEServer);
            }
        catch (SocketException e)
            {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server.");
            junk = e.ToString();//this keeps the compiler from complaining
            return;
            }

        //send command to enable monitor frames
        try
            {
            server.Send(MonitorCommand, 36, SocketFlags.None);
            }
        catch (SocketException e)
            {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to write monitor command.");
            junk = e.ToString();//this keeps the compiler from complaining
            return;
            }

        //-problem code starts here--------------------------------------------
        while (TerminateFlag == false)
            {
            if (server.Available > 35)
                {
                //only go here if we have enough data available to process
                //get the next header
                TelemetryHeader.readHeader(server);

                //read the rest of the packet and ignore
                int recv = server.Receive(AGWServerData,
                                          TelemetryHeader.MessageSize,
                                          SocketFlags.None);

                //Is it a telemetry packet?
                if (Detector.isTelemetry(AGWServerData,TelemetryHeader.SourceCallsign))
                    {
                    if (CallFilter.Find(TelemetryHeader.SourceCallsign))
                        MainList.ProcessPacket(AGWServerData, Detector, this);
                    }
                }//close If (server.Available).......
            }//close while (terminateflag)......
        //-problem code stops here-------------------------------------------
        }//close MainAPRSTW_Main
```

You can see where I've delineated the problem code. If I leave this code in, the child forms only partially populate and the program goes non-responsive. Here's a screen shot.

http://www.blandranch.net/Files/broke.jpg

If I comment out the problem code, all the child forms paint. Here's that screen shot.

http://www.blandranch.net/Files/working.jpg

So it is obvious to me that I need to do something different. I would guess that the loop is just too tight. Is that the case or is there something else about it that's wrong?

The question is, what is the right approach? Do I use Backgroundworker? Is there another way?

Chuck

Comment: SO, I sprinkled some Application.DoEvents() calls in the loop. I saw this while researching Peter's suggestion and other posting related to my issue. That let's the program work. I will look into restructuring things to use a different approach on the IO, but at least I can work on functionality rather than pull my hair out over this loop issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a BackgroundWorker or the thread pool.  The UI thread should never be blocked.  Going into a loop like that blocks the UI thread from being able to process UI update messages (like redrawing controls or updating new entries).

In your case, I suggest using BeginConnect and BeginSend instead of Connect and using asynchronous IO to do the processing the background.